# Silverlight RIA Authentication service, Profile propeties With grouping

Tags: silverlight, authentication, ria

I have read MSDN and other post for Authentication using RIA and domain service in silverlight, Successfully implimented sample with Silverlight Business application template. 
But When try to modify the profile properties with group, login successful but it gives me error for loading user profile properties.

```
    <profile enabled="true" automaticSaveEnabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
      <properties>
<group name="Personal">
          <add name="FirstName" type="String" />
          <add name="FriendlyName" type="String" />
        </group>
  </properties>
    </profile>
```

"FirstName" not found.

In the user.vb class generated by business template I have added 
above two properties, but not getting how to push the Group name there
(please note, the user trying to login its profile properties stored under .